# Laravel working in master branch but not updating HTML in localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, version-control

I'm working in my master branch on my computer locally. I've updated some HTML and I'm loading the page up in localhost. However, the HTML is not being updated but my CSS is, what do I do? I haven't had this problem before!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
php atrisan config:cache
```

on your terminal. May be the page serving from cache that's why not reflecting the changes.

Comment: Now I'm getting whoops something went wrong message

Comment: Laravel make cache copy of all the views under

your_project/storage/framework/views

php atrisan config:cache

clears these cache.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this commands to remove the caches:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
composer dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
```